# Change Cell Reference based on Cell Row/Column Inputs

Tags: excel

I have been looking for an answer to this problem. I imagine it's fairly simple, but I think the problem is I don't really know exactly how to search it.

Basically, I want to change the reference in the formula by updating the column and row cells.

[image: Example]

So, since the column and row cells say Q & 8, the formula updates to pull from Q8.
If I were to change the column to R, it would pull from R8 and equal 20.

Surely this is straightforward.. right? Please??

Thanks!!

Comment: you will want INDIRECT which allows you to create a text string and convert it to an actual  reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(P12,COLUMN(INDIRECT(P11&"1"))))
```

For explaination how does it work please read about functions `INDIRECT`, `ADDRESS` and `COLUMN`

Comment: You only need: `=INDIRECT("'OtherTab'!"&P11&P12)`

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you. I had found Indirect, but had only seen examples of its use in much more complex problems. Is there a way to make the tab selection function in the same way? For instance, I could change a different cell from 'OtherTab' to 'OtherTab2' and it would populate this formula? @ScottCraner

Comment: @HR-32091-24 you just concatenate that into the string: `=INDIRECT("'"&P10&"'!"&P11&P12)`